# .Net Runtime Error with Error ID 0 -

Tags: iis, asp.net

I'm getting the following error on a web server and have no idea what's causing it. The error is:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source: .NET Runtime
Event Category: None
Event ID: 0
Date: 7/21/2009
Time: 4:49:40 PM
User: N/A
Computer: PSA-APPLICATION
Description:
```

> The description for Event ID ( 0 ) in
>   Source ( .NET Runtime ) cannot be
>   found. The local computer may not have
>   the necessary registry information or
>   message DLL files to display messages
>   from a remote computer. You may be
>   able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to
>   retrieve this description; see Help
>   and Support for details. The following
>   information is part of the event: .NET
>   Runtime version 1.1.4322.2407- Setup
>   Error: Failed to load resources from
>   resource file Please check your Setup.

Any pointers would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've got a .NET app that's not behaving somewhere (to point out the obvious).  It's not *necessarily* an ASP.NET app, though, it could be something else.

Something things I would try going along the ASP.NET culprit idea:

- make sure your app is not sharing an application pool with another ASP.NET app using a different version of the .NET framework
- Make sure all of your ASP.NET apps are configured to use the proper version of the .NET framework in IIS Mgr.
- Reregister ASP.NET for any version of the framework necessary.  Run `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` from within the framework folders in `%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]\`
- Reinstall the various versions of the .NET framework and service packs.  Maybe something has gone missing after an update or something.

You can also use a tool like [**Sysinternals Process Explorer**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) which will highlight .NET Clr processes (default is bright yellow).  This will help you to determine what other .NET apps you have running on the server in addition to ASP.NET in the case that your problem is not related to ASP.NET.